# Is it possible to run Windows 8 in VirtualBox from .vhd created by disk2vhd?

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, backup, vhd

I want to upgrade my Windows 8.1 machine to Windows 10, but first I need to do complete refresh of the PC. As it's hard to remember everything for backup (like settings in various programs etc) I usually use [disk2vhd](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee656415.aspx) to make a snapshot of my whole system (all partitions) and backup it on external drive. This way I can boot the PC as virtual machine in case of emergency (and mount as data partition in normal cases). I have Windows 7 and Windows XP backed up this way, but for Windows 8 it just won't boot.

I tried to find solution to this on many forums (also VirtualBox forum), but seems like nobody found solution to this (or doesn't want to share knowledge).

Does anybody know if it's possible to create a backup of Windows 8 that can be booted as virtual machine later?

**EDIT: more detail**

To create vhd I run disk2Vhd and check all partitions except external USB stick used for Dropbox, OneDrive etc, and the drive that I'm saving backup to (which is external USB drive).

Then in VirtualBox I create new VirtualMachine, choose Windows 8.1 64 bit and my previously saved VHD as machine's drive. When booting the machine I get boot failure: no bootable media found.

For Windows 7 and Windows XP it just booted normally provided I included all partitions in disk2vhd.

I tried to mess with some options of virtual machine but without success. Enabling EFI in settings just changed the error to some different errors, but still no boot (I can provide details on this if it's relevant).

Some people on the forums stated that disk2vhd doesn't copy boot partition. But is this the case? Why it works for Win 7 and Win XP then?

Comment: Of course it is. Specific problems need to be described in detail

Comment: @Ramhound I can provide more detail if needed. If it's possible to do it I would love to know how.